# Are requests for off-site resources on-topic here?

Tags: support, scope, questions

I flagged this question as off-topic: [New Jersey budget plan](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/28598) with the reason:

> This question does not appear to be about governments, policies and political processes within the scope defined in the help center.

Because it asks for an off-site resource. But the flag was declined.

I looked at the [on-topic page](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) again, and it doesn't seem to say anything about off-site resource requests (though I remember that being suggested as a close reason a while back. I guess it didn't make it?)

The one (self-)answer to the question is basically only a link to the off-site resource. The answer is criticised for this, and some of the arguments against link-only-answers are outlined here: [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really "good answers"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231).

I can only see a request for an external resource like this ending with a pretty much link-only answer. That's why I thought the off-site resource requests were universally off-topic across the different stack exchange networks.

But my off-topic flag was declined. Does that mean off-site resource requests are on-topic here? Or maybe I just used the wrong close reason (although the question is still open)?

---

There seem to be 2 similar questions on meta:

- [Are requests for references on-topic?](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178)
- [Is asking for resources on treaties off topic?](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3222)

But in both cases the resource or reference that is asked for is able to be included in the answer itself (not through a link). I'm specifically asking about the case where the resource is too big to fit in an answer, in this case a legal document, and the only possible answer is pretty much a link to the resource.

Comment: Very similar, possible duplicate: [Are give-me-data-only questions on topic?](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3033/11249)

Comment: @Carpetsmoker I think it's very close (I didn't find that one before). But I don't think requests for data are off-topic by default. Only when those requests can pretty much only generate link-only answers. At least I'd like this Q to be closed as a dupe (rather than deleting) so the other one can be found easier next time.